# How to build a stm32 with cmake

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, stm32

I want to build a stm32 project with cmake. The host is Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-98-generic.

This is my CMakeLists.txt script file. I wrote this file refer to my Makefile. The Makefile works well.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

set (CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-as)
set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set (CMAKE_OBJCOPY arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
set (CMAKE_OBJDUMP arm-none-eabi-objdump)
set (CMAKE_SIZE arm-none-eabi-size)

set (TARGET hUart)
set (MCU stm32f401re)
set (BOARD stm32f401re-nucleo)
set (APP uart)

set (CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS
  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
)
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS
  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
  -fno-common -fsigned-char -fmessage-length=0
  -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow
  -Os -ffunction-sections -data-sections
  -g3
  -std=c11
)
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
  -spec=nosys.specs -spec=nano.specs -u _printf_float -u _scanf_float
  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-map=${TARGET}.map,--cref
)

add_definitions (
  -DNDEBUG
  -DSTM32F401xE -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT
  -DUSE_STM32F4XX_NUCLEO
)

project (${TARGET})

include_directories (
  drivers/${MCU}/cmsis
  drivers/${MCU}/hal
  bsp/${BOARD}
  projects/${BOARD}
  apps/${APP}
)

file (GLOB STARTUP
  drivers/${MCU}/startup/*.s
)
message (STATUS "[DBG]: ${STARTUP})
file (GLOB CMSIS_SRCS
  drivers/${MCU}/cmsis/*.c
  drivers/${MCU}/hal/*.c
)
file (GLOB BSP_SRCS
  bsp/${BOARD}/*.c
)
file (GLOB APP_SRCS
  projects/${BOARD}/*.c
  apps/uart/*.c
)
message (STATUS "[DBG]: ${APP_SRCS})

set (LINKER_SCRIPT drivers/${MCU}/linker/STM32F401VEHx_FLASH.ld)

add_executable (${TARGET}.elf ${STARTUP} ${CMSIS_SRCS} ${BSP_SRCS} ${APP_SRCS} ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

add_custom_target (${TARGET}.bin
  DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary ${TARGET}.elf ${TARGET}.bin
)

add_custom_target (${TARGET}.lst
  DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJDUMP} -Sdh ${TARGET}.elf > ${TARGET}.lst
```

The error log like this.

```
ompiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
Build flags: -mcpu=cortex-m4;-mthumb;-mfloat-abi=hard;-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16;-fno-common;-fsigned-char;-fmessage-length=0;-Wall;-Wextra;-Wshadow;-Os;-ffunction-sections;-data-section
Id flags:

The output was:
1
cc1: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: t
cc1: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: -
cc1: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: s
cc1: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: e
cc1: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: c
cc1: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: t
cc1: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: i
cc1: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: o
cc1: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: n
cc1: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: s
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libg.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x16): undefined reference to `_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


The C compiler identification could not be found in "/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c.243r.c

The C compiler identification could not be found in "/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c.253r.c

The C compiler identification could not be found in "/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c.260r.c

The C compiler identification could not be found in "/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c.245r.l

The C compiler identification could not be found in "/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c.249r.l

The C compiler identification could not be found in "/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c.231r.i

The C compiler identification could not be found in "/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c.293r.s

The C compiler identification could not be found in "/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c.247r.l

The C compiler identification could not be found in "/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c.244r.r

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-c++
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
1
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/local/bin/make" "cmTC_ff236/fast"
/usr/local/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff236.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff236.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff236.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff236.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj   -c /home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/te
Linking C executable cmTC_ff236
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff236.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff236.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj  -o cmTC_ff236
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff236.dir/build.make:98: cmTC_ff236] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hoya/hWorkspace/EmbeddedStudy/projects/stm32f401re-nucleo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_ff236/fast] Error 2
```

Now, how can I fix this?

And, how to create the dependencies? I can do it '-MM -MT' options on Makefile.

All other options are exactly same as Makefile.

Comment: Cross-compiling things like `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`,
 compiler, flags are better described in [toolchain file] (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html): it is **too late** to change `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` in `CMakeLists.txt`. Note, that linker script should be part of linker flags, it is not sufficient to pass it to `add_executable` call.

Comment: Thanks, a lot.
I change the linker configuration. `set (LINKER_SCRIPT drivers/${MCU}/linker/STM32F401VEHx_FLASH.ld)  set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -spec=nosys.specs -spec=nano.specs -u _printf_float -u _scanf_float -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-map=${TARGET}.map,--cref -Wl,-T ${LINKER_SCRIPT})`
And, there is an error too.

Comment: Update the question post with separated `CMakeLists.txt` and toolchain. As for `unrecognized gcc debugging option` warnings, it seems that instead of `-data-sections` it should be `-fdata-sections`.